# How to raise the margin of text only on desktop version?

Tags: javascript, responsive

I'm new to Javascript. I'm trying to raise the margin of the text only on the desktop version, not on mobile. Could you  help me find the problem.

```
<p id="myID">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, prima harum elitr te pri. Vix partiendo sententiae ad. Duo at amet dicam tempor. Numquam ceteros concludaturque in eum, id nec adhuc aliquando scriptorem, has ea consetetur cotidieque consectetuer. In verear neglegentur eam.</p>   

  <script>
    
      let screenwidth=window.innerWidth;
      
    
          if (screenwidth > "768px")
              {
            document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft = "150px";
      }
             
      else {
          document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft= "0px";
      }
      </script>
```

Unfortunately I couldnt find the problem by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `"768px"` by `768`. Must be a number and not a string :)

Answer (score 2):

`window.innerWidth` will return a number not string so it should be

`if (screenwidth > 768)` instead of  `if (screenwidth > "768px")`

```js
let screenwidth=window.innerWidth;
      if (screenwidth > "768")
              {
            document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft = "150px";
      }else {
          document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft= "0px";
      }
```

```html
<p id="myID">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, prima harum elitr te pri. Vix partiendo sententiae ad. Duo at amet dicam tempor. Numquam ceteros concludaturque in eum, id nec adhuc aliquando scriptorem, has ea consetetur cotidieque consectetuer. In verear neglegentur eam.</p>
```

you can do it using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in css as well something like

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #myId {
     margin-left: 150px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #myId {
     margin-left: 150px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**screenwidth is number**

```
<p id="myID">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, prima harum elitr te pri. Vix partiendo sententiae ad. Duo at amet dicam tempor. Numquam ceteros concludaturque in eum, id nec adhuc aliquando scriptorem, has ea consetetur cotidieque consectetuer. In verear neglegentur eam.</p>




 <script>    
  let screenwidth=window.innerWidth;          
      if (screenwidth > 768){
        document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft = "150px";
  }             
  else {
      document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft= "0px";
  }
  </script>
```